# Maven. Find versions of included dependencies by dependency

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, version

Is it possible, given a dependency such as shown below to determine the versions of included dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

For example, can we determine which version of [javax.servlet-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api) tomcat-embed-core uses as dependency?

I would like to use the same version of javax.servlet-api in a sub-module. But I don't want to include the whole tomcat-embed-core dependency just to get the right version of javax.servlet.api.

(Optional question: Is there an easy way to do this in IntelliJ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Intelij you can right click on the pom -> maven -> show effective pom.

Or I would say best is from the command line:

```
mvn dependency:list | grep tomcat
```

Comment: `pom -> maven -> show effective pom` or `mvn dependency:list | grep javax.servlet` did the trick.